# PyCord Modals broken after update from 2.0 to 2.4

Tags: python, discord, pycord

As I have had to update my PyCord Bot from Pycord version 2.0.0B4 to 2.4 due to deprecation of the old Discord API, however I have run into issues with all my commands using modals.

I get interaction fail when I use slash commands to initalize them in discord and in console I don't get any warnings.
I have tried to look through the change logs and also the current documentation for modals in PyCord, but I don't see any changes nor differences to the way they work and the way I have implemented it.

Below is an example of one my implementations of modals in my bot.

I have this slash command:

```py
    @slash_command(name="role", description="Add buttons to assign/unassign role") # Command to spawn role assignment buttons
    async def role(self, ctx, role: Option(Role, description="Role to generate assign/unassign buttons for", required=True)):
        print("Code reaches this")
        modal = RoleAssignButtonModal(role=role)
        print("Code never reaches this point")
        await ctx.interaction.response.send_modal(modal=modal)
```

And the modal it initializes is this one:

```py
from discord.ui import InputText, Modal

class RoleAssignButtonModal(Modal):
        def __init__(self, role) -> None:
            super().__init__("Button description")
            print("Code does not reach this point")
            self.role = role
            
            self.description = "**This role is for {role_mention} of the community**"
            self.assign_btn_label = "Assign Role"
            self.unassign_btn_label = "Unassign Role"
            
            self.add_item(InputText(label="Button description", placeholder=self.description, style=discord.InputTextStyle.long, required=False))
            self.add_item(InputText(label="Assign button label", placeholder=self.assign_btn_label, required=False))
            self.add_item(InputText(label="Unassign button label", placeholder=self.unassign_btn_label, required=False))

        async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
            role = self.role
            if self.children[0].value is not None:
                self.description = self.children[0].value
            if self.children[1].value is not None:
                self.assign_btn_label = self.children[1].value
            if self.children[2].value is not None:
                self.unassign_btn_label = self.children[2].value
            
            print(f'Adding button for {role.name}')
            view = RoleAssignmentView(role, assign_btn_label=self.assign_btn_label, unassign_btn_label=self.unassign_btn_label)
        
            await interaction.channel.send(
                    content=self.description.format(role_mention=role.mention),
                    view=view
                )
            await interaction.response.send_message("Buttons generated...", delete_after=0.1)
```

I have tried to mark where it breaks using print statements and it is somewhere in the initialization of discord.ui.Modal, however I cannot figure out why or how.

Any clues?

Comment: You have a problem in the initialization of the Modal class

Answer (score 1):

In the initialization of the `Modal` class, it requires an additional parameter, `id`, which is a unique string identifier for the modal, in your `RoleAssignButtonModal` class, you need to pass this identifier to the parent class when calling `super().__init__()` and it will work properly.

edit: There was a change in the way modals work in the newer versions of Pycord 2.4, I applied this and had to modify some other names

```
from discord.ui import View, Button, InputText
import discord

class RoleAssignButtonModal(View):
    def __init__(self, role) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.role = role

        self.description = "**This role is for {role_mention} of the community**"
        self.assign_btn_label = "Assign Role"
        self.unassign_btn_label = "Unassign Role"

        self.add_item(InputText(placeholder=self.description, custom_id="button_description", style=discord.InputTextStyle.long))
        self.add_item(InputText(placeholder=self.assign_btn_label, custom_id="assign_button_label"))
        self.add_item(InputText(placeholder=self.unassign_btn_label, custom_id="unassign_button_label"))

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        role = self.role
        values = interaction.values
        if values.get("button_description"):
            self.description = values["button_description"]
        if values.get("assign_button_label"):
            self.assign_btn_label = values["assign_button_label"]
        if values.get("unassign_button_label"):
            self.unassign_btn_label = values["unassign_button_label"]

        print(f'Adding button for {role.name}')
        view = RoleAssignmentView(role, assign_btn_label=self.assign_btn_label, unassign_btn_label=self.unassign_btn_label)

        await interaction.channel.send(
            content=self.description.format(role_mention=role.mention),
            view=view
        )
        await interaction.response.send_message("Buttons generated...", ephemeral=True)


Also in command you now have to use the `send_modal` method
```

from discord_slash import SlashContext, Option
from discord import Role

```
@slash_command(name="role", description="Add buttons to assign/unassign role")  # Command to spawn role assignment buttons
async def role(self, ctx: SlashContext, role: Option(Role, description="Role to generate assign/unassign buttons for", required=True)):
    print("Code reaches this")
    modal = RoleAssignButtonModal(role=role)
    print("Code never reaches this point")
    await ctx.send_modal(modal=modal)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, however it still does not seem to initialize the modal. Any clue to what else is missing?

Comment: This seem to work now, however can you specify what exactly what version you are using? I am on 2.4.1 and there is no such things as MessageComponents (I can't seem to find anything in the documentation either). I am able to now initialize the parent modal, however it now stops when I create the InputText fields. I have tried it my way and your way, neither works and still no error generation.

Comment: I adapted the answer for 2.4.1 it should work :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but it still doesn't want to play ball. The code is stuck at self.add_item(InputText.... and I have no clue as to why.